# Summation over combinations

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Can I reduce the following sequence into a single term. If so someone please point me in the right direction?

$$
\Gamma = \sum_{i=1}^{r} \binom{n-i}{r-i} \, 
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Gamma = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^r \binom{n-i}{r-i}=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^r \binom{n-i}{n-r} = \binom{n-r}{n-r} + \binom{n-r+1}{n-r} + \cdots + \binom{n-1}{n-r} = \binom{n-1+1}{n-r+1} = \binom{n}{n-r+1}$. This is called the Hockey-Stick identity, and can be proven by induction or using Pascal identity.